# POST/Create multiple items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using the below to add one product that has a name and a brand via API call. I would like to be able to submit an array of 'products' and then add then to my DB.

Could anyone suggest:
  1) How would I do this in the controller?
2) How would I structure the API POST body?

Current call looks like:

```
 http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products?brand=brand&name=name
```

My Controller:

```
    def create
        @newProduct = Product.create(product_params)
        if @newProduct.save
            render json: {message: "Product created"}
        else
            render json: {error: "Failed to create product"}
        end
    end

    private

    def product_params
        params.permit(:name, :brand)
    end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a new route in routes file with line below

```
  get 'create_multiple_products'
```

Send data in an array

```
{"products":[
    {"name":"playstation"}, 
    {"name":"xbox"}, 
    {"name":"blueray"}
]}
```

then add a new method in controller and call the create in a loop

```
  def create_multiple_products
     response["products"].each do |p|
        Product.create(  p )
     end
  end
```

The above is pseudocode, you might want to try a test driven approach setting up expected api and matching with returned data with rspec. http://matthewlehner.net/rails-api-testing-guidelines/